# Sublime - delete all lines containing specific value

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a 900mb log file which I can open in SublimeText 3. This file is bloated with lines similar to the following.

`10/08/2014 23:45:31:828,Information,,,,ExportManager: ,No records to send and/or not connected`

How can I filter out all the lines which contain `No records to send and/or not connected`

Comment: While the below solutions work, this type of job should really be done with sed/awk for large files.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can do a regular expression search-and-replace:

Click Find > Replace.

Ensure that the Regular Expression button is pressed.

For the Find What field, put:

```
^.*No records to send and/or not connected.*\n
```

Leave the Replace With field empty.

Click *Replace All*

Comment: The full stop/period at the end is important, without it, it won't work. Alternatively, you could use this: `^.*No records to send and/or not connected\S.*$`

Comment: This solution is the only feasible one if you're operating on a large file. My machine got stuck for several minutes when I did `Ctrl+Shift+K` with 200,000 lines selected.

Comment: Imma try this with my 26 000 000 lines file :')

Answer (score 76):

i could not get the regex to work so I used Alt-F3 approach from this answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/452189/how-can-i-filter-a-file-for-lines-containing-a-string-in-sublime-text-2/598999#598999

1. **Select** string of interest
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to go into multi-cursor mode on all occurrences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on Mac OS X)
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> [see comments] (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac)
4. Copy-paste selection to another buffer
5. <kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: Two things: (1) You can [link to an individual answer like this](http://superuser.com/questions/452189/how-can-i-filter-a-file-for-lines-containing-a-string-in-sublime-text-2/598999#598999) (2) You should summarize the other answer here (and specialize it to answer this question as appropriate).

Comment: You can replace steps 3 and 4 with `CTRL + L`, which expands selections to whole lines, including line break.

Comment: For those like me cursed by a MAC key scheme : `Ctrl+Cmd+G` to for multi-cursor on all occurences, `Cmd+L` to expand lines, and the usual copy/paste

Answer (score 73):

For people that don't want to write a regex - you can just select the search string, hit `ctrl+cmd+g` or pick "Quick Find All" from the menu, which will get you selections for each matching string; from there `Home` will move every selection cursor to the start of the line, `shift+End` will select every matching line, and `del, del` will delete all of them.

Multiple cursor editing is fun!

Comment: This is a very useful more generalized tip. My objective was to delete all lines containing a string. I ended up selecting one instance of it then used "QuickFind" with the shortcut  `Ctrl+Cmd+G` as Leonid suggests for selecting all those strings. After this I could go directly to "Delete Line" `Ctrl-Shift-K` and surgically all the lines with this string were removed in an instant. Sublime Text really is the best text editor I've ever used.

Comment: Is ctrl+cmd+g the same as ctrl+alt+g on Windows? I couldn't get this to work

Comment: @black panda For windows "Quick Find All" is alt+f3 - Thanks Leonid +1

Comment: If you are like me and you do not have a Home button, you can also use CMD + <- (left arrow)

Comment: You can also use cmd + L to expand selection to line.

Answer (score 36):

This is what i found for the windows users:

1. Select the string (every line containing this string is to be removed).
2. Press ALT+F3 .
3. Press Ctrl+L .
4. Press Delete .

Answer (score 27):

Neither of the regex code suggested above worked in my case, but this did work:

```
.*(text in question).*
```

Comment: It will let empty lines on your code, is that you want to? If not, add `\n` or `$` at the end: `.*(text in question).*\n`

Comment: If lines are having "abc/xyz/something" like structure, to use regex add ' \ '. For example if we have to search anything in between abc/ and /something then the expression will be :  abc/\.*.*\/something

Comment: Works for me, If you need multiple matches like I did, use `|` like so: `.*(a).*|.*(b).*|.*(c).*`

Answer (score 11):

A simple way of doing it is:

- 1 Open Sublime Text
- 2 Find => Replace (Ctrl + H)
- 3 in Find write the desired text
- 4 click Find All
- 5 press ctrl + shift + K to remove all the lines where this search is present

This is a quick solution to remove some lines that contains some text

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are the correct ways, but if you want to get rid of the rows with even a single string then do,
Find -> Replace -> put `^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*\n` In the find section and keep replace with blank. Hit the replace all button this will delete all the rows with even a single string in it.

Answer (score 1):

I like the manual edition solution, very good.

But.. have you tried to use `cat` and `grep -v` to filter out the lines and redirect to another file? Maybe better than learning regex.. (personally I always start with regex and end with editing the files myself).

In Windows you use `findstr /v`.

So you would do:

```sh
# in bash
cat my.log | grep -v "No records to send and/or not connected" > new.log
```

or

```
# in cmd
cat my.log | findstr /v "No records to send and/or not connected" > new.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem editing a sitemap

This worked for me:

1. Copy the last word in the lines that you want to delete
2. Find all
3. Press delete to delete the entire line

Answer (score -1):

Find -> Find all (this will mark the lines having the keyword)
Then go to Edit->Line->Delete line